# Can I test for daylight saving time (DST) using PHP date()?

Tags: php

I'm looking at PHP `date()` documentation and thought that `'I'` would tell me whether the date supplied was in DST. So I expected the following:

```
$d = strtotime('2012-07-01 12:30:00, Europe/London'); // this is in DST
$bool = date('I',$d); // 1
```

but got this:

```
$bool = date('I',$d); // 0
```

Obviously I'm reading the documentation wrong. I know I can do this using `dateTimeZone()` transitions, but is this not a feature of `date()` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `strtotime` you get an integer. You have lost all information of timezone, DST etc, you just get an integer. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

If you want to work with that kind of information, you should use the `DateTime` class and functions: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

You could, but I think you're better off using `DateTime`, set the current timezone to wherever you wish information from:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

(from the `date()` manual, example 1: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php )

Comment: You are right, `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` then `date('I');` works as expected.