# Cakephp 3.6.14: $dateObject->i18nFormat('dd MMM, yyyy h:mm:ss a ') wrong time

Tags: php, cakephp, time, format, datetime-format

Datetime in database is : `2019-02-15 10:00:00` when I use this code to format and display it

`$dateObject->i18nFormat('dd MMM, yyyy h:mm:ss a ');`

I get wrong datetime (2 hours ahead): `15 Feb, 2019 12:00:00 am`

How I can fix that?

Comment: Might be due to DST, check more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20418074/6160662)

Comment: @Viney whatever time I put I get back 12:00:00 so I guess it doesn't read time part from database at all

Comment: Was the column maybe previously a date, and you've changed to datetime but not cleared the ORM cache?

Comment: @GregSchmidt that was it! thank you Greg :) my fault....